# Prove Linearity

Tags: proof-writing, time-series

Given the following time varying model:
$Z(t) = \alpha*t*z(t-1)$,
how do I go about proving linearity? The issue I keep running into with a number of approaches is that because Z(t) is dependent on Z(t-1), I always end up with some inscrutable function within the function.

For transparency this is homework, some I'm happy for general guidance over a full solution.

**Edit:** The question explicitly says "Prove linearity" not "prove or disprove linearity." And the professor has used these homework's for years. So... take that for what it's worth. This is in the context of time series.

Comment: If $z(t)=a\, t\, z(t-1)$ then $z(t)=a^t \,t!\, z(0)$ which does not look like a linear function of $t$ or of $a$

Comment: Yeah... that was exactly the conclusion I was coming to.... wanted some better minds to prove me wrong.

Comment: alpha is a constant. Is that important?

Comment: That still makes it not look linear in $t$

Comment: Maybe "prove linearity" means something else in context. What course is this? Are there related problems/examples?

Comment: Karl, this is for a time series statistics course. Specifically we're working on response impulse response models. I can't find a super good similar question.

Comment: You need to clarify what is meant by "linearity" here. Linear with respect to what? Certainly not $t$. But it is a linear condition on $z$. That is, if $b_1,b_2$ are two constants, and $z_1,z_2$ are two functions that both satisfy this condtion, then so is the function $b_1z_1(t) + b_2z_2(t)$.